# Is it possible to interchange sum and integral when the series doesn't converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, uniform-convergence

Suppose a series $\sum f_n$ of integrable functions on $[0,1]$ does not converge uniformly, is it possible that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)dx$$ still holds?

Comment: If you consider equality as either both quantities are equal and finite or both are infinite then just the usual suspect $f_n=n\mathbb{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$ will do.

Comment: Equality may happen. But in general it is false.

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Thank you! The case $f_n = n \mathbb{1}_{(0, \frac{1}{n})}$ is the one that both sides are infinite, right? Do you have an example when both sides are equal and finite?

Comment: @JCAA Yes, in general we need the series to be uniformly convergent. Do you have an example when the equality holds and both sides being finite?

Comment: @Yujian Lebesgue integration does not require uniform convergence, as an example, although the Riemann integral does

Comment: See the usual discussion of "convergence theorems" in a text on measure theory ... Fatou's lemma, dominated convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem.  Also see Fubini's other theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} - \frac{(n-1)x}{1+(n-1)^2x^2}\right)$$
this series have continuous sum $0$, on interval $[0,1]$, though converges non uniformly and holds
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} \,dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln (1+n^2)}{2n}=0=\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$$